# I use Socialite login in Laravel 10 and i send request from Ajax on click google icon button but in laravel give Error like

Tags: ajax

I use Socialite login in Laravel 10 and i send request from Ajax on click google icon button but in laravel give Error like

index:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=329926922829-euj4d61nis6528vvscdcocmlfv20o116.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fseekr%2Fapi%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=openid+profile+email&response_type=code&state=XmWfKcitcWpkIQJXAPgCiEu2sKov0VLILp83zjhT' (redirected from 'http://localhost/seekr/api/google/login') from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

i want the solution of this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.